A question when verifying the Green function of Helmholtz operator
The green function $$G(\mathbf{r})=-e^{ikr}/(4\pi r)$$ satisfies the equation
$$\nabla^2 G(\mathbf{r}) + k^2 G(\mathbf{r})  = \delta(\mathbf{r})$$
But if we try to verify it by the formula
$$ \nabla^2 (fg) =  g\nabla^2f + f\nabla^2g+ 2\nabla f\cdot  \nabla g\;, 
$$
where $f=-\frac{1}{4\pi r}$ and $g=e^{i\vec k\cdot \vec r}$, the last term would generate an extra term. Can anyone explain?

Welcome To Physics.SE Yuchuan Wei. The equations in your question were very unclear, I've suggested an edit to improve their readability. I highly advise you to take a look at this MathJax guide to help you to better format your future posts.

why do you think your 3rd equation has anything to do with the 1st one being a Green's function? (you can also add equation numbers with \tag{label} where label is the number/label).

@YuchuanWei: polar coordinates can be a little bit tricky (especially when the divergence is involved.)  Try using the chain rule, and remember that $\nabla r \equiv \hat r$, and $\nabla \cdot \hat r \propto 1/r$.

You might go back to have a look at the derivation of Green’s theorem.

You won’t get a delta function by applying the standard rules of differentiation. You have to integrate both sides of the PDE against some smooth function and show that the resulting distributions are equal
